# Installing Laravel On CentOS 7

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, centos7

I am trying to install Laravel on CentOS7, I ran this command:

`composer install`

But I'm getting an exception:

`[ErrorException] file_put_contents(./composer.lock): failed to open stream: Permission denied`

I have tried to solve it but I couldn't.
Please help. Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Looks like you have a permission problem

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.